# Android Media Recorder start failed exception

Tags: android, audio, mediarecorder

I am having problem with media recorder in android. I am recording an audio which works well with LG P500 but the same code is not working on Samsung GT - S5360. I am getting error as start failed -22.

This is the code I am using:

```
final MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL‌​);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GP‌​P);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
recorder.setOutputFile(path);
try {
    recorder.prepare();
    recorder.start();
} catch (Exception e) { Log.d(TAG, "Exception : " + e); }
```

When debugging got cause as null in logcat.

Please suggest me some solution.

Comment: any code or logcat will be appreciated. we cant provide a solution just like that.

Comment: This is the code I am using:

final MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
recorder.setOutputFile(path);
try
{
 recorder.prepare();
 recorder.start();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
 Log.d(TAG, "Exception : " + e)
}

Comment: Finally I found the solution after a long searching, I added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" /> permission and now my code is working well.

Comment: Where did you find such permission? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

Comment: I have put the same permission in my manifest still the app is crashing on recorder.start()

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and I tried installing a voice recorder from the play store to check. It didn't allow me to record VOICE_CALL too. From that I realised some device manufacturers don't support this. So record with the MIC if the device doesn't support VOICE_CALL.

Comment: The VOICE_CALL option requires [CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT permission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource#VOICE_CALL), which is only granted for privileged apps.

Answer (score 1):

The permission suggested by the op did not work for me, probably because it does not exist :)

If you are getting this error check the way you are setting up the media recorder. In my case it only failed in some devices as well. I was doing this for all devices running Os version > API 10:

```
mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_WB);       
mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_WB);
```

Turns out that the faulting device was running JB but didn't support wideband, so changing it to raw/narrowband worked:

```
mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.RAW_AMR);      
mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
```

Answer (score -3):

Based on the comment of the actual poster... he suggested his answer in the comment. Putting this into an actual answer, hoping that it helps others:

The OP added the following permission and his code worked well for him:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />`

Comment: This is either deprecated or nonexistent.